# Compare strings in PHP

Tags: php, post, strcmp

I'm trying to compare a POST variable with a string. Can someone help me see what in my PHP code is not written correctly? I've tried both '==' and '==='. Thank you for your help.

```
$action = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['action']);    
if(strcmp($action, "save") == 0){
    //do stuff
}elseif(strcmp($action, "load") == 0){
    //do other stuff
}else{
    //do even more stuff
}
```

Comment: What's the output if you print $action or var_dump($action) after you assign its value?

Comment: Is `$mysqli` a valid connection?

Comment: Yes, it's valid. I'm sorry to waste your time. I saw that it was an error in the script that called it.

Answer (score 1):

why not simply use

```
if ($_POST['action']=='save'){

}elseif($_POST['action']=='load'){

}
```

don't understand the mysql in this contenxt

Comment: thank you for your answer. I actually saw it was an error in the code that calls the script and the code works now. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to do this, but try casting `$aciton`, like `(string)$action`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually saw it was an error in the code that calls the script and the code works now. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

== is used to see if the two sides of comparison are equal, while === is used to check to see if they're identical meaning they are equal AND of the same type.

As for your code, you should just be able to do

```
if($action == 'save'){
   echo 'save';
}
elseif ($action == 'load'){
   echo 'load';
}
else{
   echo 'none';
}
```